# module 'graphlab' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphlab

I am trying to build a recommendation engine using the `graphlab` library. 
I read in the `graphlab` documentation that `graphlab` is built for Python 2.7.
I am using Python 3.5.

I have successfully installed `graphlab` with *tar.gz* but while importing `graphlab`, I am getting following error.

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 import graphlab
>         2 #graphlab.get_dependencies()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/graphlab/**init**.py in
>   ()
>        48 from graphlab.util import set_runtime_config
>        49 
>   ---> 50 import graphlab.connect as _mt
>        51 import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
>        52 from . import visualization
>
> AttributeError: module 'graphlab' has no attribute 'connect'

Can anybody please guide me about what could be wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far for resolving this issue?

Comment: I have tried this: `pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/email_id/token/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz` I have token from Turi. I have tried installing with tar.gz of GraphLab. But still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute error for connection shows mismatch in their supported version for the attributes. Its always better that you can make again a `virtual environment` with supported version to install `python` and `conda` again. You may refer to [Link](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html)